# Is it possible to slow down scrollRangeToVisible?

Tags: iphone, scroll, uitextview

I'm creating an app that will play a song with AVAudioPlayer, and I setup a textView to scroll through the lyrics of the song as it's playing, but all the scrolling options I've found scroll to the bottom of the size of the textView's contents almost instantaneously. Is there a way to control the speed? Or if I have to load multiple scrollRangeToVisible calls through the duration of the song, is there a way to make it animate smoothly instead of "jumping" from point to point on from the scrollRangeToVisible calls? This is the code I'm using

```
scrollPoint.y= [textView.text length];
[textView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];

// also tried this
//[textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([textView.text length], 0)];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put your code to set the content offset inside a UIView animation block, you can set the duration as necessary. e.g.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: <duration>
                 animations:^(void) {
                     self.textView.contentOffset = <offset>;
                 }];
```

Don't use `-[UIScrollView setContentOffset:animated:]` as this will override your block's animation duration

Comment: Much obliged good sir, worked like a charm. Can I ask though, what the ^(void) call is. Never seen it before.

Comment: that code worked great for getting my textView to autoscroll, but now my UI buttons aren't clickable, so the play/pause stop, FF, rew, etc buttons can't be clicked. In fact, even my tab bar buttons can't be clicked either.

Comment: And actually I found this method to be better, in that I can interact with the interface while the animation is occuring `[UIView animateWithDuration:(self.myMusicPlayer.duration - 20) 
         delay:0 
       options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
       animations:^(void) {self.textView.contentOffset = scrollPoint;} 
       completion:nil];`